# How Media tags (<audio> and <video> elements) are handled by Event Loop?

Tags: javascript

How Media tags (`<audio> and <video> elements`) are handled in event loop execution in Javascript. If Javascript is single threaded then, Why video is not paused if event loop is busy with some other operation?

Comment: Javascript is a thing your browser DOM computation is an other. If your JS is changing your DOM, your browser will interpret the new DOM even if your javascript is still running. Your video/audio elements are not computed directly by your JS but by the browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, only a very few parts of what makes a media player in a browser is powered by javascript:

- Handling of user-interaction
- DOM manipulations (the [HTMLMediaElement API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement))

Everything else, i.e fetching, de-muxing, decoding, playing, rendering etc. is all part of browser's code, and is not part of the Event loop, and probably not written in javascript (it sure isn't in main vendors' browsers).